# Phaser Animation is slow in mobile devices (Specially in Android devices), any suggestion or fix?

Tags: phaser-framework

Code snippet

```
sprite.animations.add('congrats', Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('Congratulations', 1, 140, "", 4), 20, true);
sprite.animations.play('congrats', 20, false,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phaser is a JavaScript library, and in general JavaScript is slower. This is especially noticable on mobile devices, as opposed to PC's or laptops which usually have enough CPU "horsepower" to compensate for this.

So your question is impossible to answer, without knowing..:

- Which Android devices did you try? A "lower-end" device such as a Samsung Galaxy S II?
- Is it slow even on "high-end" devices like a Galaxy S7 or Xperia XZ?
- What resolution does your game run in?
- How many sprites are on screen at once and how large are they?
- Are you using many `Phaser.Emitter` with lots of particles?
- the P2 physics library can be CPU intensive, are you using that?
- etc.

Comment: 1. Galaxy s6, Nexus 5, One Plus 3T.                                                                    2. Its not running in any fixed resolution, it will be adjusting based on the screen                                                                                                             3. Using single sprite image size around 4MB.                                         4. We using box2d plugin

Comment: The devices seem fast enough I guess. Any physics engine takes lots of CPU time, including box2d. Arcade physics are more light weight but only does simple rectangle overlaps/collisions. If possible try to use that instead. Other than that, try experimenting by making a minimal game program, and then add more back in (enemies, physics, particles etc.) to see when it slows down. Or you could also use the [Chrome Javascript profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool#make-a-recording) to see which code takes up the most CPU time.